# How to indent second line with textwrap?

Tags: python, word-wrap

I have this python code which imports textwrap. However, i need to put a space infront of all lines which have a single digit at the front.

```
line1 = [" S  M  T  W Th  F  S"]
line2 = ["--------------------"]
line3 = [" 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31"]

print(''.join(line1))
print(''.join(line2))
line3Str = ''.join(line3)
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=20) 
word_list = wrapper.wrap(text=line3Str) 
for element in word_list: 
  print(element)
```

I have tried to put different spaces between the 7 and 8 or make a different list for the second line down but no matter what I encounter this issue.

**Expected output:** (Hyphen is space)

```
-1 ...        
-8 ...     
15 ...       
22 ...     
29 ...
```

**Actual output:**

```
-1 ...       
8 ...   <         
15 ...         
22 ...        
29 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to right-align every line but last one, so you can replace last two lines in your program with:

```
for element in word_list[:-1]: 
    print(element.rjust(20))
print(word_list[-1])
```

Or, if you want to store the formatted list of strings, you can format word_list after calling wrapper.wrap:

```
word_list = wrapper.wrap(text=line3Str)
word_list = [x.rjust(20) for x in word_list[:-1]] + [word_list[-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string to be printed right aligned you can use:

```
>>> '18'.rjust(2)
'18'
>>> '8'.rjust(2)
' 8'
```